# How to use Neo4J for temporary graph calculations?

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, graph-databases

I'm completely new to Neo4J and I am struggling with a design/architecture question.

**Setup**

I have a given Graph with different nodes. That could be the a company graph with customer, products, projects, sales and so on (like in the movie example https://neo4j.com/developer/get-started/). This graph can change from time to time.

In my use case I would like to take this graph, adapt it and test some scenarios.  E. g. I would add a new product, define a new sales person with responsibilities or increase the price of a product. To the extended graph I will "ask questions" or in other words, I would use graph algorithms to extract information. The changes I made, shouldn't affect the original graph.

**Requirements**

- I do not wanna write my changes to the original graph, because every time the original graph should be the base for the analysis. Also for the reason that changing and analysing the graph can happen concurrently from different users.
- I still wanna use the power of Cypher to make the analysis, so having the graph only in the memory wouldn't do it.

**Problem**

On the one hand I do not wanna change the original graph, on the other I wanna add and change information temporarily for a specific user. Using a relational DB I would just point with an ID to the "static" part of the data or I would do the calculation in Code instead of SQL.

**Questions**

- Any best practices for that?
- Can I use Cypher directly in code (none-persistent, directly on the data in the memoty)?
- Should I make a copy of the Graph, whenever I use it (not really,
  right?)?
- Is there a concept to link user specific data to a static graph?

I am happy about all ideas, concepts and tricks! It's more about graph databases in general....Neo4J was so far my first choice.

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using feature flags in your graph by using different relationship types ?

For example, let's say you have a User that likes 10 movies in your original graph.

```
(user)-[:LIKES]->(movies)
```

Then for your experiments, you can have

```
(user)-[:LIKES_EXPERIMENT]->(othermovies)
```

This offers you the possibility to traverse the graph in the original way without loosing performance by just enforcing the relationship types. On the other hand it also offers you the possibility to use only the experiments or combining original data with experiments by specifying both relationship types in your traversals.

The same goes for properties, you could prefix properties with `experiment_` for eg. And finally you could also play with different labels. There are tons of possibilities before having to use different graph data stores.

Another possibility is to use some kind of versioning like described here :

http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/
But without the time factor.

There is also a nice plugin for it https://github.com/h-omer/neo4j-versioner-core

Comment: I feel like adding a user node and new relationships must be the solution. I need to get the feeling for that first...I may get back to you with some more questions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

1. Copy the [data folder](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations) of the original database to a new location: `sudo cp /path/to/original/data/folder ~/neo4j`
2. Run a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) container mapping the copy of data folder as the container data folder.

Something like this:

```
docker run \
--publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
neo4j
```

You can specify another ports if `:7474` and `:7686` are being used.

3. Work over this copy.

You can transform these instructions in a `.sh` file to automate the process.

Comment: That sound like a really heavyweight solution. Imagine hundreds, thousands of user using the graph for experimenting. And what if the base data changes? That can't be the best-practice. Anyway many thanks for the idea.